# Is there an explicit "non-supernatural" version of "A Hero's Journey"?

Tags: history-of, archetypes, a-heros-journey

Parts of A Hero's Journey seem to be inherently supernatural:

- Supernatural Aid
- The Meeting with the Goddess
- The Magic Flight, although I'm not sure it's inherently supernatural.

Did either Campbell, or anyone else, address in a scholarly manner either the necessity of supernatural to the Monomyth; or more explicitly, building a version of Monomyth that is supernatural-free (just as THWATF does, in a scholarly way, by analyzing existing myths and works).

Comment: Wouldn't the requirement of supernatural aid make this an empty set?

Comment: @King-Ink - I hope not...

Comment: Would technological "magic" fit your bill?  You've got stories like Elysium that fit many of the qualities of A Hero's Journey (and I'm sure someone can find a better fit than Elysium; it just popped into my head) in which lowly ex-con Matt Damon is given super tech powers and shot into the magical realm where he defeats the dragon and saves the world.  Lots of good hard scifi fits the bill.

Comment: @JasonPatterson - yes and no. Such a story fits the bill as an example (I think). But a **single story** doesn't fit the question - I'm looking for a **scolarly analysis** based on pattern in many stories, ala Campbell

Answer (score 5):

Christopher Vogler's list from [ Christopher Vogel, The Writer's Journey: Mythic Structure For Writers (2007)] is not explicitly supernatural.

```
1. The Ordinary World
2. The Call to Adventure
3. Refusal of the Call
4. Meeting with the Mentor
5. Crossing the Threshold to the Special World
6. Tests, Allies and Enemies
7. Approach to the Innermost Cave
8. The Ordeal
9. Reward
10. The Road Back
11. The Resurrection
12. Return with the Elixir
```

Karate Kid I think fits the mold of a non super-natural hero's journey. With that said I thing Campbell is high on his own fumes and that he wrongly imposes the "mono-myth" the over completely unrelated cultural stories.

Answer (score 3):

The hero's journey is non-supernatural. It's just the terminology that makes it seem so. For example Supernatural Aid = Mentor.

KalBashir.com has a detailed 2100+ stage hero's journey version / analysis.

Comment: +1 for being correct. The events in the hero's journey are archetypal plot developments; Campbell uses terms evocative of fantasy to illustrate them, but the important details of each step are A) What it means for the hero's personal transformation, and B) How it affects the story's ability to advance.